# Clausius's Carnot Cycle Equation Derivation

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetic-theory, carnot-cycle

**In his paper clausius describes a Carnot cycle and he continue arguing like below:**

In order to make an analytical application of the method...we will assume that all the changes which the gas undergoes are *infinitely* small. We may then treat the curves as straight lines as they are represented in the accompanying figure. (...)
the magnitude $dk$ is the increase on the pressure, while the gas at the constant volume $of$ has its temperature raised from $r$ to $t$ that is by the differential $t-r=dt$. (...) the quantity of heat which must be communicated to a gas while it brought from any former condition in a definite way to that condition in which its volume $=v$ and its temperature its $=t$, may be called $Q$ and the changes of volume in the above process **[the figures]**, which must here be considered seperately may be represented as follows: $ef$ by $dv$,$hg$ by $d'v$, $eh$ by $δv$, $fg$ by $δ'v$.During expansion from volume $v$ to $v+dv$ at constant temperature $t$ the gas must recieve the quantity of heat: $$\frac{dQ}{dv}dv$$

Correspondingly, during expansion from $v+δv$ to $v+δv+d'v$ at temperature $t-dt$ the quantity of heat :

$$[(\frac{dQ}{dv})+\frac{d}{dv}(\frac{dQ}{dv})δv-\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dQ}{dv})dt]d'v$$

**My question is about the last equation. How it is derived?**

the paper can be found here:https://archive.org/details/secondlawthermo01kelvgoog/page/n86
(page 76)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) I think your first round bracket is misplaced. It should be immediately before $\frac{d}{dv} \frac{dQ}{dv}$

(a) The stuff in the square brackets is a first order Taylor expansion of $\frac{dQ}{dv}$ regarded as a function of $v$ and $t$, in order to find the appropriate value of $\frac{dQ}{dv}$ for the leg 'de', in terms of the value for the leg 'ab'.

Comment: Could you please explain more I can't see how the terms δv and dt come out through a taylor series of two variables...

Comment: Put $\frac{dQ}{dv}=X.$ Then $$X(v+\Delta v, t+\Delta t) = X(v, t) + \frac{dX}{dv} \Delta v + \frac{dX}{dt} \Delta t.$$Like much of his notation, Clausius's sign convention for temperature change is odd.

Comment: Please have a look in a question about the same given paper. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480325/clausius-paper-on-the-motive-power-of-heat-on-the-laws-which-can-be-deduced